# Python: create dictionary from file input

Tags: python

File content:

**files.txt**

```
RPM: psmisc-22.6-24.el6.x86_64
S.5......    /sbin/fuser
RPM: python-2.7.9-0011.00.6ES.x86_64
..5......    /usr/lib64/python2.7/base64.pyc
..5......    /usr/lib64/python2.7/base64.pyo
```

I would like to create the following data structure - the example below was crated manually to illustrate expected output.

A list of files ({file: verify status} pair) as a value for each key with pkg name:

```
>>> d
{'python-2.7.9-0011.00.6ES.x86_64': [{'/usr/lib64/python2.7/base64.pyc': '..5......', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/base64.pyo': '..5......'}], 'psmisc-22.6-24.el6.x86_64': [{'/sbin/fuser': 'S.5......'}]}
>>> for k, v in d.items():
...     print(k, v)
... 
('python-2.7.9-0011.00.6ES.x86_64', [{'/usr/lib64/python2.7/base64.pyc': '..5......', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/base64.pyo': '..5......'}])
('psmisc-22.6-24.el6.x86_64', [{'/sbin/fuser': 'S.5......'}])
```

I was able to add pkg name to the dictionary so far but not sure how to proceed further:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os

d = {}

with open('files.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        (k, v) = line.split()
        if k.startswith('RPM'):
            d[v] = []

print(d)
```

**Testing:**

```
$ python test.py 
{'python-2.7.9-0011.00.6ES.x86_64': [], 'psmisc-22.6-24.el6.x86_64': []}
```

I'm not also sure if this data structure is optimal so any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: What is your issue? It seems like you got everything working?

Comment: Please include in your post any errors you are receiving, or problem statements about your code.  What do you need help with?

Comment: I want a list of files (`{file: verify status}` pair) as a value for each key with pkg name. The desired data structure was created manually as a example.

Comment: Just a suggestion, but you should add ^ that to your original post so people don't have to read through the comments to find the request.  You'll attract more help that way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os

d = {}

with open('files.txt', 'r') as f:
    pkg = None
    items = None
    for line in f:
        (k, v) = line.split()
        if k.startswith('RPM'):
            if pkg:
                d[pkg] = [items]
            pkg = v
            items = {}
        else:
            items[v] = k
    if pkg:
        d[pkg] = [items]

print(d)
```

Output:

```
{'psmisc-22.6-24.el6.x86_64': [{'/sbin/fuser': 'S.5......'}], 'python-2.7.9-0011.00.6ES.x86_64': [{'/usr/lib64/python2.7/base64.pyc': '..5......', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/base64.pyo': '..5......'}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex and `itertools.groupby`:

```
import itertools
import re
new_data = [[a, list(b)] for a, b in itertools.groupby([i.strip('\n') for i in open('filename.txt')], key=lambda x:bool(re.findall('RPM:\s', x)))]
second_data = [re.sub('^RPM:\s', '', b[0]) if a else [dict([re.split('(?<=\.)\s+', c)[::-1] for c in b])] for a, b in new_data]
final_data = {second_data[i]:second_data[i+1] for i in range(0, len(second_data), 2)}
```

Output:

```
{'python-2.7.9-0011.00.6ES.x86_64': [{'/usr/lib64/python2.7/base64.pyc': '..5......', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/base64.pyo': '..5......'}], 'psmisc-22.6-24.el6.x86_64': [{'/sbin/fuser': 'S.5......'}]}
```